# How to send a Discord message with a button attached using CURL in PHP?

Tags: php, discord

I am trying to use CURL in PHP to send a discord channel message with a button attached to it. I am not familiar with CURL and it doesn't seem like restcord supports message components.

GETTING THIS ERROR: {"code": 50035, "errors": {"components": {"0": {"_errors": [{"code": "MODEL_TYPE_CONVERT", "message": "Only dictionaries may be used in a ModelType"}]}, "1": {"_errors": [{"code": "MODEL_TYPE_CONVERT", "message": "Only dictionaries may be used in a ModelType"}]}}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}

```
<?php
$channelID = "IDHERE";
$webhookurl = "https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/" . $channelID . "/messages";

$json_data = json_encode([
    // Message
    "content" => "test",

    // Text-to-speech
    "tts" => false,

    "components" => [
        "type" => '1',
        "components" => ["type" => 2, "label" => "test", "custom_id" => "help_me", "style" => 1],
    ],


], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


$ch = curl_init($webhookurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bot token'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
// If you need to debug, or find out why you can't send message uncomment line below, and execute script.
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Lol, uncomment the `echo response;` line and show the output.

Comment: @AndyGee it just gives me this. {"components": ["0"]}